# setting element.text to a value in directive does not render in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

So, in my directive I'm updating the text of an element. I have span and I'm just updating it with a number. The element is set as below. I even set the innerHTML of the element. In the console element is updated correctly but in the view it is not reflecting.

[span.ng-isolate-scope, 
 context: span.ng-isolate-scope, 
 text: "20h:51m:8s", 
 innerHTML: "20h:51m:8s"]

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('countdown', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                date: '@',
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                future = new Date(scope.date);

                    element.text  = future;
                    element.innerHTML  = future;


            }
        }


    }]);
```

This is the html

```
<span countdown date="2016-10-07T08:15:39.566Z"></span>
```

Comment: If possible, provide the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `element` parameter is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches, not the HTML element itself, so try this: `element.text(future);`

[angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)